# Power Apps Reset function wont work for default value

Tags: powerapps-forms

I have created a basic rich text editor with a default value (instruction on what users must do)its a SharePoint list. I also have added an icon (to delete the default text) so users don't have to do it manually. The reset icon works if I start typing in the rich text box; however, it won't remove/delete the default text.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have to create a variable with the instruction text, possibly in the "On Visible" property of your screen and then use your reset icon to set the variable to `Blank()`

eg.

> OnVisible: `Set(gblDefaultText,"Open Jira, see if there any URGENT tickets.")`
>
> Reset Icon: `Set(gblDefaultText,Blank())`
>
> And then set the Default property of your Rich Text Editor to `gblDefaultText`